# Hermiticity of Slater-Koster hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, tight-binding

From the paper written by Slater and Koster, some of the tight binding Hamiltonian seemed to change sign under a sign flip. For example
$$E_{s,x}=l(sp\sigma)$$
Suppose we have two atoms (A and B), each having an $s$ and $p_x$ orbital. They are connected along the $[100]$ direction. From my understanding, since the A$\to$B is in $[100]$, the hopping integral element between orbitals $s - p_x$ of A and B is $(sp\sigma)$.  Then, along the reverse direction, B$\to$A direction is $-[100]$, so the hopping integral from $p_x-s$ of B-A is $-(sp\sigma)$. This renders a non-Hermitian Hamiltonian.

`So I wonder if there is something wrong from my understanding? For example` $(ps\sigma)$ `has an opposite sign?`

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Add the cases for nanocluster in response to the OP's comment.

You should look the whole lattice structure, instead of isolate two atoms.
It is a lattice periodic structure, saying along $[100]$ direction with a lattice constant $a$:

```
- A - B - A - B - A - B - A - B - A - B - A - B - A - B - A - B -
```

Let examine the matrix element with a given Bloch wave vector $k$ in x-direction with A atom in the origin ($S_a$ in the center).
$$
 \langle X_b \vert H \vert S_a \rangle = \left(e^{-ika} - e^{ika}\right)   (sp\sigma) = 2i\sin ka (sp\sigma).
$$

[image]

The two Bolch phases are from the B atoms in the right (located at $a$) and in the left (located at $-a$), and the minus sign between these two phase is due to the odd parity of $X_b$ orbital.

---

**Edit: If it is a nanocluster, then each orbital of the atom is an independent basis.** Let's label the center A atom the index $n$, and the left B atom $n-1$, the right B $n+1$. The overlapping intergals among them and their corresponding conjugate elements (matrix transport element) are:
\begin{align}
  \langle X_{n-1,b}\vert H \vert S_{n,a} \rangle &= (sp\sigma) \,\, \text{ conjugate to } \,\, \langle S_{n,a}\vert H \vert X_{n-1,b}\rangle = (sp\sigma);\\
  \langle S_{n,a}\vert H \vert X_{n+1,b} \rangle &= -(sp\sigma) \,\, \text{ conjugate to } \,\, \langle X_{n+1,b}\vert H \vert  S_{n,a}\rangle = -(sp\sigma);
\end{align}

**The orbitals of the left atom B ($n-1$) are not the same bases as the orbitals of the right atom B ($n+1$). They won't mix under matrix transport.**

---

Then, examine the conjugate matrix element with B atom as origin (the $X_b$ at the center):
$$
 \langle S_a \vert H \vert X_b \rangle = \left(-e^{-ika} + e^{ika}\right)   (sp\sigma) =- 2i\sin ka (sp\sigma).
$$

[image]

It satisfies the Hermitian relation
$$
   \langle X_b \vert H \vert S_a \rangle^\dagger  = \langle S_a \vert H \vert X_b \rangle
$$

In case of $k=0$, these two matrix elements are both zero due to symmetric consideration.

Comment: I am not looking at tight binding for bulk material, I am looking at nanoparticle, so there is no phase factor in the system.

Comment: For nanostructure, each atom's orbital is a different basis, For $S_{n,a}$ - $X_{n+1, b}$, its  conjugate element is $X_{n+1, b}$ - $S_{n,a}$, not $X_{n-1, b}$ - $S_{n,a}$. Your reversing direction senario is not existing.